# Wpf binding элементов к RibbonTab

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь создать приложение с лентой. Каждая вкладка на ленте отвечает за отдельную функциональность (по аналогии с вкладками браузера). Модели представления главного окна и вкладки выглядят примерно так:

```
//Модель представления вкладки
public class TabVm
{
    public string Header { get { return "Tab 1"; } }

    public string Content { get { return "Some content"; } }
}

// Модель представления главного окна
public class MainVm
{
    public ObservableCollection<TabVm> Tabs { get; private set; }

    public TabVm SelectedTab { get; set; }

    public MainVm()
    {
        SelectedTab = new TabVm();
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabVm> { SelectedTab };
    }
}
```

Представление для вкладки представляет собой словарь ресурсов с шаблоном данных (содержимое вкладки) и элементом RibbonTab (содержимое ленты на вкладке):

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <RibbonTab x:Key="RibbonTabKey">
        <RibbonGroup Header="Group 1"/>
    </RibbonTab>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TabVm}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Возник вопрос с тем, как вытащить из словаря RibbonTab и использовать его для представления элементов на ленте? Т.е. для вкдадки TabVm на ленте должна появиться одна пустая группа элементов с наименованием "Group 1"

Представление главного окна:

```
<RibbonWindow ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Ribbon Grid.Row="0" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
            <Ribbon.TabHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Ribbon.TabHeaderTemplate>
        </Ribbon>   

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding SelectedTab}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ViewModelDataTemplateSelector}"/>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

**UPDATE**

Итак, на основе многочисленных ответов @VladD было решено сделать следующее:

В представление вкладки добавить стиль для RibbonTab, в котором будет определено значение свойства ItemsSource.

```
<Style TargetType="RibbonTab">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource">
        <Setter.Value>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <RibbonGroup Header="{Binding Group1Name}"/>
                <RibbonGroup Header="{Binding Group2Name}"/>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

В представлении главного окна использовать StyleSelector.

```
    <Ribbon Grid.Row="0" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}"
            ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource RibbonTabStyleSelector}">
        <Ribbon.TabHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TabVm}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Ribbon.TabHeaderTemplate>
    </Ribbon>
```

Таким образом, удалось сделать привязку плоской модели представления к иерархичному представлению.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обновление: итак, нам нужна иерархия VM-объектов.

```
public class TabVm
{
    public string Header { get { return "Tab 1"; } }
    public string Content { get { return "Some content"; } }
    public IEnumerable<TabGroupVm> Groups
    {
        get { yield return new TabGroupVm() { N = 1 };
              yield return new TabGroupVm() { N = 2 }; }
    }
}

public class TabGroupVm
{
    public int N;
    public IEnumerable<string> Buttons
    {
        get { yield return "Button 1/" + N; yield return "Button 2/" + N; }
    }
}
```

Для этого случая работает следующий XAML:

```
<Ribbon Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
    <Ribbon.TabHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TabVm}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Ribbon.TabHeaderTemplate>
    <Ribbon.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="RibbonTab">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Groups}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="RibbonGroup">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Buttons}"/>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Ribbon.ItemContainerStyle>
</Ribbon>
```

Для виртуализации по типу `TabVm` можно использовать `Ribbon.ItemContainerStyleSelector`.

---

Обновление: по уточнённому условию, должно работать так:

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="..."
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="..." ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Ribbon Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
            <Ribbon.TabHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- эту часть можно выгрузить во внешний resource dictionary -->
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TabVm}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Ribbon.TabHeaderTemplate>
        </Ribbon>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding SelectedTab}">
            <!-- и эту часть можно выгрузить во внешний resource dictionary -->
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TabVm}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

---

Вы не должны пытаться [сохранить UI-элемент](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4387349/276994) в resource dictionary, это не вполне правильный и чистый путь.

Правильнее будет воспользоваться `CompositeCollection` для того, чтобы добавить в UI ещё один элемент к вашей VM-коллекции.

Это выглядит примерно так:

```
<RibbonWindow
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="..." ...>
    <RibbonWindow.Resources>
        <!-- контент, можно унести вниз в ContentControl -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TabVm}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- нужно, чтобы сохранить binding через границу не-DO (объяснено ниже) -->
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TabCollection" Source="{Binding Tabs}"/>
    </RibbonWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Ribbon Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
            <!-- у нас нет общего шаблона для header'а, поэтому применяем 
                 стиль, в который можно положить нужные DataTemplate'ы -->
            <Ribbon.TabHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="RibbonTabHeader">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <!-- по неизвестным мне причинам требуется указать и ключ -->
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TabVm}"
                                      x:Key="{x:Type vm:TabVm}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </Ribbon.TabHeaderStyle>
            <Ribbon.ItemsSource>
                <!-- коллекцию составим из частей: -->
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <!-- этот таб будет всегда -->
                    <RibbonTab Header="Predefined tab">
                        <RibbonGroup Header="Group 1"/>
                    </RibbonTab>
                    <!-- остальное берём из Tabs -->
                    <CollectionContainer
                        Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource TabCollection}}"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </Ribbon.ItemsSource>
        </Ribbon>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding SelectedTab}"/>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

Трюк с `CollectionViewSource` понадобился вот почему. Дело в том, что `CompositeCollection` не является `DependencyObject`'ом, а начит, не принимает участия в visual tree. Это значит, что через границы тега `<CompositeCollection>` не передаётся `DataContext`, поэтому `Binding` к `DataContext`'у внутри `CompositeCollection` не сработал бы. Трюк взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19271605/276994)

Альтернативные методы обхода проблемы с `DataContext`'ом: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446923/276994), [[2]](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

Comment: Ваш ответ не решает проблему сопоставления модели представления и ее представления на ленте. Вкладки - это отдельные модули. Они предоставляют свое содержимое (содержимое окна и элементы управления на ленте) в виде словаря ресурсов (возможно, это неправильное решение). Суть в том, что SelectedTab нужно представить в двух местах (содержимое окна и содержимое закладки ленты). А информация о содержимом представлений хранится в модуле. И ее нужно подгрузить.

Comment: @Vlad: Тогда, возможно, я не совсем правильно понял задачу. У вас список табов должен соответствовать коллекции Tabs один к одному или нет?

Comment: Да. Каждый таб живет своей жизнью. При переключении таба меняется содержимое окна.

Comment: @Vlad: Если нарушается синхронизация, возможно, вам просто нужно реализовать INPC для `MainVm`/`SelectedTab`? Я предполагал, что у вас это реализовано, просто вы не включили в вопрос для краткости.

Comment: @Vlad: То есть: что не работает с текущим кодом?

Comment: Ваш код работает также, как и мой (разве что фиксированная вкладка не привязывается, но тут все ясно). Отображается набор вкладок, при изменении текущей вкладки, меняется и содержимое окна. Тут все хорошо. Для отображения содержимого окна используется DataTemplate в связке с Selector'ом. Не понятно, как описать подобный "селектор" для элементов на ленте?

Comment: @Vlad: А, вам нужен как бы `TabHeaderTemplateSelector`? А для чего? По какому признаку вы хотите выбирать? Можно попробовать обойти это через Binding с конвертером.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29718/discussion-between-vlad-and-vladd).